# ReactJS onClick doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble getting `onClick` working in reactJS. I put together [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c4hedjw0/) and am sure its something trivial. Code is below, see fildle for (not)working example:

```
var Bar=React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
    <div className="bar" style={{width: this.props.width+"px"}}>                {this.props.width}</div>)
  }
})

var ClickableBar=React.createClass({

    clickBar: function(e) {
        alert('clicked');
        this.setState({width:220});
    },
    render: function() {
      return (
      <Bar onClick={this.clickBar} width={this.state.width}/>
      )
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ClickableBar width="20"/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass the handler through as a prop:

```
var Bar = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.props.onClick} className="bar" style={{width: this.props.width+"px"}}>{this.props.width}</div>
    );
  }
});
```

Otherwise, your div will be created without a click listener on it, since a "Bar" doesn't really exist in the dom (only the div is actually there).

Answer (score 0):

And you also missed to initialize your `state`

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return {
    width: 30
  }
}
```

Otherwise you will get an error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

I prefer using style in this way

```
render(){
  var myStyle = {width: 200, backgroundColor: green};
  return <div style={myStyle }> ... </div>
}
```

It also works with React. [`Fiddle example`](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/325/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just need to bind the function with the DOM element.

```
<Bar onClick={this.clickBar.bind(this)} width={this.state.width}/>
```

or

```
<Bar onClick={() => {this.clickBar()}} width={this.state.width}/>
```

---

If you want to call function by passing the event:

```
<select onClick = {(event) => {self.funcName(event)}} >
```

---

If you want to call function by passing arguments:

```
 <select onClick = {(event) => {self.funcName(event, arg1)}} >
```